# NotesDocument opens twice

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus

I have an application that uses 2 servers and has 2 databases.
Server 1 - Main application
Server 2 - Calendar

When launching a document in the main application, I have a link to the calendar entry.  This opens the calendar entry on the calendar server.  There is a link in the calendar entry that launches the document in the main application.

This action is performed using the notesuiworkspace.editDocument function.

The problem I have is that in my scenario above, I have the main document open in the application (1 document).  I then click on the button to launch the calendar entry (I now have 2 documents open, the document in the main application and the corresponding calendar entry).  If I then click on the open main document button, it opens another copy of the main document.  If the user is unaware they then cause save conflicts.

This has occurred for several versions of Notes, currently on 10.

Code from Main Application Server 1 docuemnt to open calendar entry:

```
Set uidoc = ws.CurrentDocument
Set doc = Srv1.GetDocumentByUNID(uidoc.FieldGetText("CalenderUNID")
If Not (doc Is Nothing) Then
  Set uidoc = ws.EditDocument(True, doc)
End If
```

Code from Calendar Entry to Main document on Server1

```
sID = uidoc.FieldGetText("MainUNID")
Set doc = Srv1.GetDocumentByUNID(sID)
If Not (doc Is Nothing) Then
  Call uidoc.Close(True)
  Set uidoc = ws.EditDocument(True, doc)
End If
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Have now done so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the [documentation](https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/9.0.1/appdev/H_EDITDOCUMENT_METHOD.html) for "EditDocument" in NotesUIWorkspace:

> Set notesUIDocument = notesUIWorkspace .EditDocument( [editMode] , [notesDocument] , [notesDocumentReadOnly] , [documentAnchor$] , [returnNotesUIDocument] , [newInstance] )

You see, there is an optional parameter "newInstance". And if you read further it sais:

> newInstance
>
> Boolean. Optional. If True (default), opens a new instance of notesDocument (parameter 2) in the UI. If False, changes focus to an existing instance of notesDocument if one exists, or to a new instance if one does not exist. This parameter does not apply if notesDocument is not specified or the document has a target frame.

Just change your code accordingly:

```
Set uidoc = ws.EditDocument(True, doc,False,"",True,False)
```

But beware: There is a (little) bug with the "newInstance" flag: 
If you create a new main document and save it. Then open the calendar document and click the link back to the main document, then there will always be a second window with the main document unless you closed and reopened the main document in the meantime... A "new" document that has not been closed and reopened after saving is not recognized by the newinstance flag...

Comment: Thank you @Torsten - this comes down to RTFM - haha!  I got really excited, however the little bug essentially means it does not work for me.  Do you know in what instance it does work?  It is not common but it's the cause of a few rep save conflicts and I would like to close it off.  I will log it with HCL too.